# most efficient way in MySQL to store VARCHAR that is almost always NULL?

Tags: mysql

I have an online form where users have to submit a few multiple choice answers, and have the option to insert their email address (to be kept up to date on the results). However, only few people to actually do this.

So currently I have a table with 3 columns: `submission_id INT`, `encoded_answers varchar(20)` , and `email VARCHAR(50)`. However, given that 95% of the email entries are NULL, this is quite wasteful.

Of course I could use two tables: a large one with `submission_id` and `encoded_answers`, and a smaller one with `submission_id` and `email`. But is there also a solution within 1 table? Sort of a sparse-type column, that would only take space if the field is not NULL?

Comment: Why shy away from normalization? The multi-table approach is the right one.

Comment: a length of 50 for an email seems pretty risky to me...

Comment: It is odd you don't have a user-type record to represent, among other things, the email address in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why is it wasteful? Have you done any tests to confirm this? A column with no value doesn't really take up much space, perhaps a byte per column per row. That's what `VARCHAR` is all about, being variable length.

Further, arbitrarily limiting your fields to short lengths is actually considered harmful. It is not uncommon for an email address to exceed 50 characters. Note that the storage requirements of `VARCHAR(50)` and `VARCHAR(255)` are the same for strings of equal length. It is only for columns of length 256 and beyond where you'll pay in the form of an additional length byte.

Remember that MySQL will arbitrarily truncate your data if it doesn't fit in the field. This is really **bad** for important data like email addresses.

Comment: Very useful advice, it seems I had misunderstood that. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, storage of a string in a varchar(50) is the same as the same string in a varchar(255).  But as the string is loaded from the storage engine into memory, strings have to be stored in memory in a fixed-length row, so RAM is allocated according to the maximum length of the column.  This is the format used for sorting and temp tables, and those buffers can spool to disk.  So defining varchar(255) for strings that never need that length can be wasteful  and even blow away your available disk space.

Comment: I've used MySQL for a long time and I've never had problems where `VARCHAR(50)` saved the day. What you're saying is technically true, but unless you're dealing with data that's **guaranteed** to be a particular length, like ISO country codes, SHA-type hashes, or data subjected to application-level length requirements, it's probably better to be more lenient and go with the default of `255`. If you're dealing with billions of email addresses, proper normalization will pay bigger dividends here than a shorter length on the field. `INT` is 4 bytes. `VARCHAR(50)` is 150 if UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Not in **SQL**, no. You should think about using a **NoSQL** engine for such task.